# How do a validate a relationship at the database level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see that you can validate a belongs_to at the model level by using validates_presence_of (or something like that), but in the Migration we use a simple belongs_to :owner. There doesn't seem to be an intuitive means to validate the constraint in the database as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, you want to validate data in your migration file?

Comment: You can add a db constraint as follows: `t.integer :owner_id, null: false`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966840/how-to-change-a-nullable-column-to-not-nullable-in-a-rails-migration

Comment: Actually if you want to validate relationship, and not just id column, you would have to add proper SQL query to your migration. However I would advise you to trust in Rails constraints through validations.

Comment: Donovan: I want to validate the relationship constraint. DamienRoche: yeah I guess that would work. I was surprised that the relationship key column was nullable. :/

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, that does go against what I have perceived to be rails best practices. At least in my reading it is mentioned, when possible, to let the database do what it does.

Comment: Can you link that reading?

Comment: Since I didn't have an exact reference to what I had read months ago here are a few summations:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122791/rails-validation-in-model-vs-migration
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367281/ruby-on-rails-is-it-better-to-validate-in-the-model-or-the-database